# Linux/sh: How to listing only files in folder (with witespace) and save into a variable in one line

Tags: shell, printf, sh, whitespace, 7zip

I try to get the lists of files in that format (with witespaces):

"file1.html" "file 2.php" "file_3.php"

```
#!/bin/sh
WEB_DIR="/volume1/web"

IFS=$'\n'
for file in $(find "${WEB_DIR}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f) ; do
  printf "\"$file\" "
done
```

output:

```
"/volume1/web/.htaccess" "/volume1/web/file.html" "/volume1/web/a b.php"
```

**and the output is perfect but... how to put this output to the variable?**

I do this...

```
IFS=$'\n'
for file in $(find "${WEB_DIR}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f) ; do
  mystring+=$(printf "\"$file\" ")
done

echo ${mystring}
```

In output I have this:

```
tmp.sh: line 48: mystring+="/volume1/web/.htaccess" : not found
```

Answer (score 3):

Note:

- The answer below accepts the premise of the question: to build a single string value with a list of double-quoted file paths, such as the one shown in the question (
  `"/volume1/web/.htaccess" "/volume1/web/file.html" "/volume1/web/a b.php"`)
- However, the OP ultimately wanted to use that string *as part of another command*, which does *not* work, because the embedded double quotes are no longer recognized as string delimiters that identify separate arguments when you reference the string variable.

  - The correct solution is to use `find ... -exec ...+` (in this case) or, generally, `xargs` to pass a list of filenames as operands (arguments) to another command; e.g., to pass the filenames to command `foo` (`{}` robustly passes all file paths, whether they contain spaces or not):
    `find "${WEB_DIR}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec foo -bar {} +`
  - If the list of filenames doesn't go at the *end* of the target command line, an intermediate `sh -c` command is necessary:
    `find "${WEB_DIR}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'foo -bar "$@" -baz' - {} +`

---

You've tagged your question [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), but your shebang line targets [sh](/questions/tagged/sh), where Bash extensions to the [POSIX shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) aren't guaranteed to be available.

In your case (it sounds like you're using `dash`, which act as `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu):

- ANSI C-quoted strings such as `$'\n'` aren't available - `$'\n'` expands to *literal* `$\n`.

  - This means that any of these 3 literal chars. - `$`, `\` or `n` serve as the field separator - in your case that just *happened* to work, because the file paths happened not to contain these characters.
- Operator `+=` isn't recognized - the whole token `mystring+="/volume1/web/.htaccess"` is treated as a *command name*, which causes the error you're seeing.

Possible solutions:

- If you do want to target Bash, replace `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/bash`.

  - Note that for your `bash` code to be fully robust, you should turn off globbing (`set +f`) in addition to setting `$IFS`.
  - Your code can be streamlined - see below.
- If not (if your code must be portable), you must find POSIX-compliant alternatives - see below.

---

Here's a **portable solution** (works with any POSIX-compliant `sh`):

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
  mystring="$mystring$(printf "\"$file\" ")"
done <<EOF
$(find "${WEB_DIR}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f)
EOF

echo "$mystring"
```

A much more efficient variant that uses `find ... -exec ... +` to produce the output with (typically) a *single* `printf` call:

```
IFS= read -r mystring <<EOF
$(find "${WEB_DIR}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec printf '"%s" ' {} +)
EOF

echo "$mystring"
```

---

The **`bash` equivalent**, using a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (`<(...)`):

```
IFS= read -r mystring < \
  <(find "${WEB_DIR}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec printf '"%s" ' {} +)

echo "$mystring"
```

---

Also note that ***GNU* `find` has a built-in `-printf` action** that supports a variety of format strings, which makes calling the external `printf` utility unnecessary:

```
IFS= read -r mystring < <(find "${WEB_DIR}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '"%p" ')

echo "$mystring"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure why we are bothering with the intermediate step of using a variable:

```
find "${WEB_DIR}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /usr/syno/bin/7z \
a "${BACKUP_DIR}/backup_webfiles_${TIMESTAMP}.7z" -xr!thumbs.db -xr!@eaDir -xr!@tmp \
-xr!#recycle -xr!lost+found -xr!.DS_Store -t7z -m0=lzma2 -ms=off -mhe -mmt -mx9 \
-v${SPLIT_VOLUME} -p"${PASSWORD}"
```

I am not sure if you have to tell 7z that the files are coming from stdin, so you might have to add a hyphen (-) where "${only_files}" used to be??

Comment: The context for your answer was lost when the OP's follow-up question, which was mistakenly posted as an _answer_, was deleted. You are correct about the intermediate variable. Not only is it unnecessary, but it _doesn't work_. Generally, you don't need `xargs` with `find`, because the `-exec` action can invoke commands directly. `7z`, as the `xargs` target command, doesn't receive filenames via _stdin_; instead, `xargs` passes them as a list of _arguments_ at the _end_ of the command line.